# jdeps command does not work with -p attribute

Tags: java, module, java-11, jdeps

When I execute this command:

```
jdeps  --module-path out --module test
```

it's fine and it prints all the information. But when I replace `--module-path` with `-p`, it throws an exception:

```
jdeps -p out --module test
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Module test not found
```

But according to java we can replace `--module-path` with `-p`:

[image: --module-path to -p]

So why does it throw the exception?

Answer (score 1):

While the options are generally consistent for multiple different programs, it's not the case with the `-p` option. The Oracle documentation for [java](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/java.html) says:

> **--module-path modulepath... or -p modulepath**
>   A semicolon (;) separated list of directories in which each directory is a directory
>   of modules.

But for [jdeps](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/tools/jdeps.html), it's:

> **-p pkg name, -package pkg name, or --package pkg name**
>   Finds dependencies matching the specified package name. You can specify this option multiple times for different packages.

#### Example of use

This example is based on a module named `msg.service.app`. It contains only has one package `msg.application`:

Getting the information about the module without using `-p`:

```
..snip..>jdeps --module-path target --module msg.service.app
msg.service.app
 [file:///C:/..snip../target/msg.service.app/]
   requires mandated java.base (@11.0.3)
   requires msg.service.api
msg.service.app -> java.base
msg.service.app -> msg.service.api
   msg.application            -> java.lang                  java.base
   msg.application            -> java.util                  java.base
   msg.application            -> msg.service                msg.service.api

..snip..>
```

Getting the information about what depends on the package `msg.service`:

```
..snip..>jdeps --module-path target -p msg.service --module msg.service.app
msg.service.app
 [file:///C:/..snip../target/msg.service.app/]
   requires mandated java.base (@11.0.3)
   requires msg.service.api
msg.service.app -> msg.service.api
   msg.application            -> msg.service                msg.service.api

..snip..>
```

Example where it's used on `java.base` to find out what depends on the `sun.util.spi` package:

```
..snip..>jdeps --module java.base -p sun.util.spi
java.base
 [jrt:/java.base]
java.base -> java.base
   java.util                  -> sun.util.spi               java.base
   sun.util.locale.provider   -> sun.util.spi               java.base

..snip..>
```